# Auto Increament a column based on Another column in Sql server 2005?

Tags: sql, triggers, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a two primary key Columns in a table. the second column based on first column. i show you the figures of them, see the splr_Slno is Based on the splr_Id.

[image]

i show you another figure for the example

[image]

when i delete a record for splr_Id '21' and splr_Slno '2' it should be like this
[image]

below there is a trigger

```
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_i] 
 ON  [dbo].[table] 
 AFTER DELETE
 AS 
 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Declarations
    declare @intSplrlid as int
    declare @autoSplrslno as int
    set @autoSplrslno=0
--Process
    set @intSplrlid = (select splr_Id from deleted)
    --set @autoSplrslno = (select splr_Slno from deleted)
    update dbo.table set splr_Slno = @autoSplrslno+1 where dbo.table.splr_Id =@intSplrlid;
```

END

the second record is deleted..., what i want is the splr_Slno should be auto generated when the record is deleted

Comment: Why you want to do this ?You want to splr_Slno to be in order like 1 2 3 4 when 2 is deleted. I mean you want to rearrange the sequence? One way is to make a cursor and update rows by iterating in loop.

Comment: because i want to delete the records from front end recommended by the user. i want that splr_Slno should be auto generated when record is deleted

Comment: Are you using stored procedure for deletion? If yes then let me know. So I can make code in SP. or If you want Trigger, I will make code in trigger.

Comment: no by using this Query "delete dbo.table where splr_Id=21 and splr_Slno=2"

Comment: and i am using a trigger for auto increament but it show an error i am updating my question

Answer (score 0):

I think following code should work. Try it in different scenario. I have just implemented logic. Not tested it. Tell me if there is any mistake.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger1] 
ON  [dbo].[table1] 
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @splr_Id INT, @increment INT = 1, @iterate_splr_Id int, @iterate_splr_Slno int
    SELECT @splr_Id = splr_Id FROM DELETED

    DECLARE cursorObj CURSOR LOCAL static FOR SELECT splr_Slno, splr_Id FROM dbo.table1 WHERE splr_Id = @splr_Id
    OPEN cursorObj
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorObj into @iterate_splr_Slno, @iterate_splr_Id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      UPDATE dbo.table1 SET splr_Slno = @increment WHERE splr_Id =@iterate_splr_Id and splr_Slno = @iterate_splr_Slno
      SET @increment = @increment + 1
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursorObj into @iterate_splr_Slno, @iterate_splr_Id
    END
    CLOSE cursorObj
    DEALLOCATE cursorObj
END
```

Comment: Sorry I used it with plan of while loop only but that I don't need and I forget to remove. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Can you explain what's is wrong? Is my logic wrong or my code has problem? Or something else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30467/discussion-between-itbeginner-and-anjali)